# Get fields values and save a TXT File (PHP)

Tags: php, file, header

I have a page that is a log online, with many fields...I want to make a button that saves the content of the fields in a txt file and automatically shows the download screen for the user... Ive tryed with :

```
$arq = "test";
header('Content-type: text/plain');
header( 'Content-Length: ' . strlen( $arq ) ); 
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="save.txt"');
print $arq;
```

But i dont know why, it saves the html of the page too! I want only the content of my variable..

what im doing wrong?

regards!

Rafael

Comment: I tried this code... it worked in my system... I am able to download .txt file...

Comment: Its downloads, okay, but why its saves the html from the page? I just want to save in the txt the content of the variable...

Comment: i am getting in .txt format only not in html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.... I put "die;" after

```
print $arq;
```

and worked. He stopped the code and saved only the content of the variable. :)